# Size Classes and UITableViewCell/UICollectionViewCell sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, xcode6

Size classes are phenomenal for specific constraints between devices. However you can't add constraints directly to a UITableViewCell or a UICollectionViewCell - specifically height and width.

I want to have a larger UICollectionViewCell on iPad Size Classes than iPhone so I always have three cells per row in portrait mode regardless of device. However, because I can't add constraints to the Cell, and adjusting the height/width directly is independent of size classes, I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: i have same problem ....if you solved this one than plz share with me....thank you

Answer (score 1):

UIViewControllers conform to [UIContentContainer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIContentContainer) protocol, so you you will be told whenever controller view's size is changing by overriding `-viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` (this new iOS 8 API is also called on rotations) changing your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` itemSize (which is responsible for cells size).